unstable WiFi with Ubuntu 22.04.05
I've got a new laptop : Lenovo Ideapad Slim 3 15IRH8. It came with Windows preinstalled, I tried a dual-boot with Ubuntu (had to deactivate secure boost and BitLock) but I wasn't happy with it so I ended up installing Ubuntu 22.04 (updated to 22.04.5 LTS) only. No more dual boot.
Unfortunately I have now WiFi problems : after a few minutes of stable and fast connection, it drops dead (it's not a slow, it's a sudden stop). I thus have to manually disconnect/reconnect to the access point to get some minutes of stable WiFi back. Sometimes it also randomly disconnects from the access point.
I have zero WiFi problems with other devices and I had no issue on this laptop with Windows. I am thus convinced the problem is not from my router/box but it's rather from Ubuntu and/or its network manager. It could also be the drivers of my WiFi card.
I've runned the diagnostic command from the WiFi troubleshooting Ubuntu webpage , it should provides all the infos needed about my laptop specs and network related files. I will provide other diagnostic outputs if needed. I really need a stable connection for my work, i would deeply appreciate if someone could help me about this.
Well, I wanted to paste the output here but my post gets flagged as "spam" so I will link the Launchpad post I made, it contains all the infos: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/818761
EDIT: output from 'journalctl --since "2024-09-21 15:15" --until "2024-09-21 15:20" -k -p emerg..err' (timeframe is set around a connection fail):
sep 21 15:18:24 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command
sep 21 15:18:56 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command
sep 21 15:18:58 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command
sep 21 15:19:00 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command
sep 21 15:19:02 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command
sep 21 15:19:04 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command
sep 21 15:19:04 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command
sep 21 15:19:08 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command
sep 21 15:19:10 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command
sep 21 15:19:42 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command
sep 21 15:19:46 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command
sep 21 15:19:48 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command
sep 21 15:19:50 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command
sep 21 15:19:50 15IRH8-GR kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to send h2c command

EDIT2: available in the launchpad post linked but here is the output of 'lshw -C network':
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: b8:1e:a4:d5:84:41
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822ce driverversion=6.8.0-40-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.178.197 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:161 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:50500000-5050ffff


What is the output of 'sudo lshw -C network' Please append the resulting output to your question. When it fails run the following from just before to just after the failing event and also append results to your question. journalctl --since "2024-07-30 00:00" --until "2024-07-30 00:30"  {with '-k' &  '-p emerg..err' flags}

Please try Ubuntu 24.04 instead. It would have better support for recent hardware

My post has been edited with required outputs @david
